# Plotting Multiple Power Functions in Python

Tags: matplotlib

I am trying to plot three power functions in python, but I am getting a value error. Here is my code. How do I fix this? Please help

Code:

```
from numpy import *
import math
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = logspace(-4, 2, 10)

m = 0.315*a**-3
r = 0.0000926*a**-2
d = 0.685

plt.plot(a, m, 'r') 
plt.plot(a, r, 'b') 
plt.plot(a, d, 'g') 
plt.show()
```

The error message:

```
 ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension, but have shapes (10,) and (1,)
```

Comment: [**We don't allow images of text (code/input/output/errors, or otherwise) on Stack Overflow**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question). Please post all text into the question with [correct formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). Questions with images of text/code/errors are routinely closed. Please also check out the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to make sure this & your future questions are suitable for this Q&A.

Comment: Thanks for the warning. Will edit now

Comment: You are calling `plot(a, d, 'g')` where `a` is a numpy array with 10 values, and `d` is a single number. Current versions of matplotlib need both `a` and `d` to have the same number of elements. For example `plot(a, np.full_like(a, d), 'g')` could be a way to draw such a constant function. Also note that `from numpy import *` isn't recommended, because it could overwrite some standard Python functions, leading to weird error messages. It is highly recommended to `import numpy as np`. By the way `plt.yscale('log')` would set the y-axis in logscale, which is probably more readable in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As JohanC suggested you need same number of elements for `a` and `d` variable. I just use his suggestions and plot a graph for you if that helps.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a = np.logspace(-4, 2, 10)

m = 0.315*a**-3
r = 0.0000926*a**-2
d = 0.685

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(4, 3), dpi=200)
plt.plot(a, m, 'r', label='a v/s m') 
plt.plot(a, r, 'b', label='a v/s r') 
# plt.plot(a, d, 'g') # As JohanC suggested you need same number of elements for a and d variable
plt.plot(a, np.full_like(a, d), 'g', label='a v/s d') # alternatively use this
plt.yscale('log')
plt.grid()
plt.legend()
```

[image]